# Android imageView in PagerAdapter has weird coordinates

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-view

So i have the custom PagerAdapter used to represent the grid 4x4 with 4 images. That PagerAdapter is set to the custom ViewPager (with swapping turned off). Now the problem is that when i try to call `getLocationOnScreen()` method on ImageView i get as output some weird coordinates (x = 1146, y = 457) which does not seem to be good coordinates (x coordinate is wider than the actual screen?). Here is the code:

```
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

    Object object = mObjectList.get(position);

    View view =  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_card, container, false);

    TextView tvTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tvTextView);

    ivImage1 = view.findViewById(R.id.ivSelectedImage1);


    ivImage1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(mContext, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                //Toast.makeText(mContext, "DOUBLE CLICK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ivImage1.getLocationOnScreen(ivLocation);
                listener.performLikeAnimation(ivLocation, ivImage1.getWidth(), ivImage1.getHeight());


                return super.onDoubleTap(e);
            }
        });


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }
```

Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong? I had similar implementation with RecyclerView with grid layout, and i was able to get good coordinates when i double tap the particular image. However i had to swap with this implementation, because i could not make it scroll like ViewPager. Main goal is to implement something like Tinder swipe cards, but only horizontal and swipe on left functionality on button click. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about using a library like [this](https://github.com/aaronbond/SwipeDeck2) where you put a `recyclerview` with a `gridlayoutmanager` with 2 `spanCount` and get the motion event into the `recyclerviewadapter`? So you can easily know which image you have pressed instead of find it by coordinates

Comment: @DennisTurri Thanks for comment! I have tried various libraries with that functionality, but i was not able to implement swipe in one direction(left) and on button click only,without  swipe motion or fling motion. Ill try this one for sure. However i have discovered that PagerAdapter for some reason if there is more than one item in the adapter list, its always look the item on position + 1... dont know why.. its really confusing.

Comment: I don't know if you already saw [this](https://github.com/CameloeAnthony/UltimateSwipeTool) but is a very useful libray for the skiping. It's differe from the other, check the card section

Comment: @DennisTurri Hi Dennis, so you suggest to use the first library (SwipeDeck2) and inside the adapter for cards i will every time instantiate the recyclerView and update its adapter? Something like adapter inside adapter?

Comment: Sorry for late answer but yes, that's the point. You can use the second library too, as you want